# Using Environment Variables in a cURL request on Azure Devops

Tags: azure, curl, azure-devops, yaml, netlify

I'm trying to upload a zip file to Netlify with a command line task using cURL on Azure DevOps.

Obviously I don't want to have my Netlify access token in the yaml file, so I've created a secret variable for it (using the UI designer) and mapped it using the syntax in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables).

However I keep getting a 401 back from Netlify. I can confirm via POSTMAN that the access token is valid. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Am I using the env variables incorrectly in the request?

here's the portion of the YAML file that deals with uploading the file.

```
- script:  >-
      curl
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer $env:ACCESS_TOKEN' 
      -H 'Content-Type: application/zip'
      --data-binary '@$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites/$env:SITE_ID/deploys
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Upload to Netlify'
  env: 
    ACCESS_TOKEN: $netlifyAccessToken
    SITE_ID: $netlifySiteId
```

Response from Netlify:

```
{"code":401,"message":"Access Denied: Origin returned bad status 401"}`
```

EDIT:

Below is the full YAML file after I managed to get it working using the 'input-macro' syntax from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  configuration: debug
  platform: x64

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: Install .NET Core SDK
  name: install_dotnetcore_sdk
  enabled: true
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.2.101'

- script: dotnet tool install -g Wyam.Tool
  displayName: Install Wyam

- script: wyam
  displayName: Build Site 

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: Zip Site
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/output' 
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip' 
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- script:  >-
      curl
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer $(netlifyAccessToken)' 
      -H 'Content-Type: application/zip'
      --data-binary '@$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites/$(netlifySiteId)/deploys
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Upload to Netlify'
```

Comment: If you do/did a write-up about how you did this, I would love to read about it. Looks like a pretty powerful static site build process using .Net and deployed to Netlify.

Comment: @talves https://www.blizard.io/posts/deploying-a-wyam-site-using-azure-devops-to-netlify

Comment: thanks, simple and great example. https://github.com/MrBliz/blizard.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use bash syntax to retrieve environment variable for that, not powershell (since you are using bash, not powershell):

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I also suspect that you need to update your env declaration:

```
env: 
  ACCESS_TOKEN: $(netlifyAccessToken) << ADO token to replace with variable from build scope
  SITE_ID: $(netlifySiteId)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same response when I make the changes you suggest.

Comment: @MrBliz You need to update all of the references to correctly point to environment variables. For example, `$(Build.BuildId)` should be `$BUILD_BUILDID`. Refer to the documentation on variables. Same goes for `$env:SITE_ID` -- that needs to be `$SITE_ID`. You can print your environment variables to make sure you're accessing them correctly.

Comment: well, i have no idea what is wrong with your request, but I'm showing you errors you have FOR SURE. or you can use debug mode, i think it prints all the variables you have @DanielMann

Comment: @DanielMann Those variable are being resolved correctly, that's not the issue.

Comment: @MrBliz I guarantee `$(Build.BuildId)` isn't being resolved correctly in a bash script, because the build system replaces periods with underscores.

Comment: @DanielMann I've posted the full working YAML and the `$(Build.BuildId)` syntax is working for me.

Comment: because the answer only partially worked in this instance. eg: mapping the env variable and using $ACCESS_TOKEN did not work.

Comment: i have no idea if that syntax is supposed to work (the `env:`), i assumed you knew what you were doing, but in the end you ended up using the proper token like i told you and it started working, so not sure what you do not like about my answer