# How to configure environment variables in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Function (.NET Core) that is configured to read application settings from both a JSON file and environment variables:

```
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .SetBasePath(_baseConfigurationPath)
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
                                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                                .Build();

BuildAgentMonitorConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Get<BuildAgentMonitorConfiguration>();
```

`appsettings.json` has the following structure:

```
{
  "ProjectBaseUrl": "https://my-project.visualstudio.com/",
  "ProjectName": "my-project",
  "AzureDevOpsPac": ".....",
  "SubscriptionId": "...",
  "AgentPool": {
    "PoolId": 38,
    "PoolName": "MyPool",
    "MinimumAgentCount": 2,
    "MaximumAgentCount": 10
  },
  "ContainerRegistry": {
    "Username": "mycontainer",
    "LoginServer": "mycontainer.azurecr.io",
    "Password": "..."
  },
  "ActiveDirectory": {
    "ClientId": "...",
    "TenantId": "...",
    "ClientSecret": "..."
  }
}
```

Some of these settings are configured as environment variables in the Azure Function. Everything works as expected:

[image: Azure Function application settings]

The problem now is to configure some of these variables in a build pipeline, which are used in unit and integration tests. I've tried adding a variable group as follows and linking it to the pipeline:

[image: Azure DevOps Task Group]

But the environment variables are not being set and the tests are failing. What am I missing here?

Comment: are those secret values? if they are, i think you need to explicitly map them to the task

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes these are secrets. I'm not sure if I understand what do you mean by "explicitly map them to the task", could you please elaborate?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962581/using-environment-variables-in-a-curl-request-on-azure-devops/53962774#53962774 second code block shows how to map secret variables to env variables for a given task

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41 - if I understood correctly, these secret variables are not set as environment variables, I need to set them using bash or powershell?

Comment: i dont know how to access them using bash or powershell, but you can assign second code block to any task and it would work, that is using yaml, i dont know off the top of my head how to use those without yaml, there should be a way, but I'm only using yaml for the last year at least, dont remember regular pipelines, feel free to upvote that answer ;)

Comment: @4c74356b41 unfortunately I'm not using YAML, but thanks anyway for your time :-)

Comment: well, you know what to google right now, should be easy

Answer (score 17):

I also have the same use case in which I want some environment variable to be set up using the azure build pipeline so that the test cases can access that environment variable to get the test passed. 
Directly setting the env variable using the EXPORT,ENV command does not work for the subsequent task so to have the environment variable set up for subsequent task follow the syntax as mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch
ie the 
**task.set variable with the script tag**

**Correct way of setting ENV variable using build pipeline**

```
- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=LD_LIBRARY_PATH]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/Projectname/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/x64'
  displayName: set environment variable for subsequent steps
```

Please be careful of the spaces as its is yaml. The above script tags set up the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH (used in Linux to define path for .so files) to the directory defined.

This style of setting the environment variable works for subsequent task also , but if we set the env variable like mentioned below the enviroment variable will be set for the specefic shell instance and will not be applicable for subsequent tasks

**Wrong way of setting env variable :**

```
- script: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/CorrectionLoop.HttpApi/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/x64
  displayName: Set environment variable
```

You can use the similar syntax for the setting up your environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately I'm not using yaml, but hopefully this will be useful to other people with the same problem.

Comment: Ok but I wonder if you are not using yaml how you are setting up the build pipeline in azure. Even the GUI of azure build pipeline is mapped to azure-pipeline.yml file.

Comment: @RuiJarimba you can mark this as the answer so that it could be helpful for others.It seems that people have preferred it over other answers.

Comment: I'm glad it is helpful to others, but I can't mark it as an answer to my question - as I mentioned in my first comment, I was looking for a solution that doesn't use yaml.

Comment: I didn't find any official document explaining this "##vso[task.setvariable variable" task. Just curious why Microsoft does not document this

Comment: By the way, I just find this syntax `##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue'` is assigning value to the variable inside pipeline, instead of to the environment variable of the shell.

Comment: @JingHe that syntax is an Azure DevOps logging command. These are used by scripts to communicate with the build agent. Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well when generating EF SQL scripts from a build task. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cshell#set-variables-in-pipeline), the variables you define in the "Variables" tab are also provided to the process as environment variables.

> Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through environment variables. The syntax for using these environment variables depends on the scripting language. Name is upper-cased, . replaced with _, and automatically inserted into the process environment

For my instance, I just had to load a connection string, but deal with the case difference of the key between the json file and the environment:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables()
              .Build();

var connectionString = config["connectionString"] ?? config["CONNECTIONSTRING"];
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll give it a try sooner or later.

Comment: If the variable is a secret then it should be exported manually.

Comment: @ArielMoraes can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **bash** then their example does not work, as they are referring incorrectly to the variables in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cshell). Instead it should be:

### Store secret

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
```

### Retrieve secret

### Wrong: Their example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "No problem reading $1 or $SAUCE"
echo "But I cannot read $SECRET_SAUCE"
echo "But I can read $2 (but the log is redacted so I do not spoil the secret)"
```

### Right:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "No problem reading $(sauce)"
echo "But I cannot read $(secret.Sauce)"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Configure KeyVault Secrets in Variable Groups for FileTransform@1**

*The below will read KeyVault Secrets used in a Variable group and add them to the Environments Variables for FileTransform@1 to use*

**setup KeyVault** [image]
**Create Variable Group** and import the values you want to use for the Pipeline. [image]

In this example we used:

```
    - ConnectionStrings--Context
    - Cloud--AuthSecret
    - Compumail--ApiPassword
```

**Setup names** to match keyVault names: (you can pass these into the yml steps template)

#These parameters are here to support Library > Variable Groups > with "secrets" from a KeyVault
#KeyVault keys cannot contain "_" or "." as FileTransform1@ wants
#This script takes "--" keys and replaces them with "." and adds them into "env:" variables so Transform can do it's thing.

```
parameters:
- name: apiSecretKeys
  displayName: apiSecretKeys
  type: object
  default:
    - ConnectionStrings--Context
    - Cloud--AuthSecret
    - Compumail--ApiPassword
stages:
   - template: ./locationOfTemplate.yml
     parameters:
       apiSecretKeys: ${{ parameters.apiSecretKeys }}
```

**... build api - publish to .zip file**

Setup Variable groups on "job level"

```
variables:
  #next line here for pipeline validation purposes.. 
  - ${{if parameters.variableGroup}}:
      - group: ${{parameters.variableGroup}}
  #OR
  #- VariableGroupNameContinaingSecrets
```

**Template file: (the magic)**

```
parameters:
  - name: apiSecretKeys
    displayName: apiSecretKeys
    type: object
    default: []
steps:
  - ${{if parameters.apiSecretKeys}}:
  - powershell: |
      $envs = Get-childItem env:
      $envs | Format-List
    displayName: List Env Vars Before
  - ${{ each key in parameters.apiSecretKeys }}:
      - powershell: |              
          $writeKey = "${{key}}".Replace('--','.')
          Write-Host "oldKey  :" ${{key}}
          Write-Host "value   :" "$(${{key}})"
          Write-Host "writeKey:" $writeKey              
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$writeKey]$(${{key}})"
        displayName: Writing Dashes To LowDash for ${{key}}      
   - ${{ each key in parameters.apiSecretKeys }}:
       - powershell: |
           $readKey = "${{key}}".Replace('--','.')
           Write-Host "oldKey  :" ${{key}}
           Write-Host "oldValue:" "$(${{key}})"
           Write-Host "readKey :" $readKey
           Write-Host "newValue:" ('$env:'+"$($readKey)" | Invoke-Expression)
         displayName: Read From New Env Var for ${{key}}      
   - powershell: |
       $envs = Get-childItem env:
       $envs | Format-List
     name: List Env Vars After adding secrets to env
```

7. **Run Task** - task: FileTransform@1

Enjoy ;)